# Database Technology - postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am quite new to postgresql. Could any expert help me solve this problem please.

Consider the following PostgreSQL tables created for a university system recording which students take which modules:

```
CREATE TABLE module (id bigserial, name text);
CREATE TABLE student (id bigserial, name text);
CREATE TABLE takes (student_id bigint, module bigint);
```

1. Rewrite the SQL to include sensible primary keys.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE module
   (
   m_id bigserial,
   name text,
   CONSTRAINT m_key PRIMARY KEY (m_id)
   );

   CREATE TABLE student
   (
   s_id bigserial,
   name text
   CONSTRAINT s_key PRIMARY KEY (s_id)
   );

   CREATE TABLE takes
   (
   student_id bigint,
   module bigint,
   CONSTRAINT t_key PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
   );
   ```

Given this schema I have the following questions:

1. Write an SQL query to count how many students are taking DATABASE.

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(name) 
   FROM student
   WHERE module = 'DATABASE' AND student_id=s_id
   ```
2. Write an SQL query to show the student IDs and names (but nothing else) of all student taking DATABASE

   ```
   SELECT s_id, name
   FROM Student, take 
   WHERE module = 'DATABASE' AND student_id = s_id
   ```
3. Write an SQL query to show the student IDs and names (but nothing else) of all students not taking DATABASE.

   ```
   SELECT s_id, name
   FROM Student, take 
   WHERE student_id = s_id AND module != 'DATABASE'
   ```

Above are my answers. Please correct me if I am wrong and please comment the reason. Thank you for your expertise.

Comment: This looks a lot like work for school. If you attempt the queries and still can't get the answer, post what you tried and we'll help. Also, you need to correct the spelling of `CREAT TABLE...` to `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: The best answer I can give is "do your own homework". You will not learn by having other people do it for you

Comment: You may want to read up on [`sub-queries`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-subquery/) and [`JOIN`s](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html).  They facilitate using more than one table in a single query.

Comment: If this is school work / home work, **say so**. Many people here will be happy to help you if you are stuck by giving you hints and pointing you in the right direction. Most people here get pretty annoyed at being asked to just write a bunch of queries though.

Comment: Folks, while I'm not much more keen on "do my homework" questions than the next guy, this person has *attempted the questions* and is asking for advice. That's a bit better than just "do it for me" and I think pointing them in the right direction is somewhat reasonable. So voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework so I'm not going to give a detailed answer. A few hints:

- I found one case where you used `´` quotes instead of `'` apostrophes. This suggests you're writing SQL in something like Microsoft Word, which does so-called "smart quotes. Don't do that. Use a sensible text editor. If you're on Windows, Notepad++ is a popular choice. (Fixed it when reformatting the question, but wanted to mention it.)
- Don't use the legacy non-ANSI join syntax `JOIN table1, table2, table3 WHERE ...`. It's horrible to read and it's much easier to make mistakes with. You should never have been taught it in the first place. Also, qualify your columns - `take.module` not just `module`. Always write ANSI joins, e.g. in your example above:

  ```
  FROM Student, take 
  WHERE module = 'DATABASE' AND student_id = s_id
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  FROM student 
  INNER JOIN take 
          ON take.module = 'DATABASE' 
         AND take.student_id = student.s_id;
  ```

  (if the table names are long you can use *aliases* like `FROM student s` then `s.s_id`)
- Query 3 is totally wrong. Imagine if `take` has two rows for a student, one where the student is taking `database` and one where they're taking `cooking`. Your query will still return a result for them, even though they're taking `database`. (It'd also return the same student ID multiple times, which you don't want). Think about [subqueries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html). You will need to query the `student` table, using a  `NOT EXISTS (SELECT .... FROM take ...)` to *filter out* students who are not taking `database`. The rest you get to figure out on your own.

Also, your schemas don't actually enforce the constraint that a student may only take `DATABASE` once at a time. Either add that, or consider in your queries the possibility that a student might be registered for `DATABASE` twice.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your time. About the Join what is the different between INNER JOIN table1 ON ... AND, and FROM table1, table2 WHERE as both will give the same answer.

Comment: @user3159044: the difference is readability. Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.